# How to center left-aligned divs with no gaps?

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to center left-aligned divs. So far, I can't do it. I had played with grid and flex and failed. This is the code that I'm playing with:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
.container {
  font-size: 0;
  background-color: DodgerBlue;
}

.container > div {
  display: inline-block;
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
  width: 210px;
  line-height: 75px;
  font-size: 30px;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<div class="container">
  <div>1</div>
  <div>2</div>
  <div>3</div>  
  <div>4</div>
  <div>5</div>
  <div>6</div>  
  <div>7</div>
  <div>8</div>
  <div>9</div>  
  <div>10</div>
  <div>11</div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Is there any way of centering these divs only using HTML/CSS? I tried `text-align: center` but the divs are not going to be left-aligned anymore. I want to center the divs while preserving their left-alignment and responsiveness.

If they're not possible to be centered, is there a way to at least make a container resize its width based on its content? I want something like this:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>

.container {
  border: 1px solid black;
  padding: 10px;
}

.grid-container {
  display: inline-grid;
  grid-template-columns: auto auto auto;
  background-color: #2196F3;
}

.grid-item {
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.8);
  border: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
  padding: 20px;
  font-size: 30px;
  text-align: center;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<h1>display: inline-grid</h1>

<div class="container">
  <div class="grid-container">
    <div class="grid-item">1</div>
    <div class="grid-item">2</div>
    <div class="grid-item">3</div>  
    <div class="grid-item">4</div>
    <div class="grid-item">5</div>
    <div class="grid-item">6</div>  
    <div class="grid-item">7</div>
    <div class="grid-item">8</div>
    <div class="grid-item">9</div>
  </div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

The problem with this is that, inline-grid can't be centered and it's not responsive.

Edit:
To clarify my question further, I want my divs to be aligned like this
[image]

The content of divs can be left,center or right. My main problem is the div aligment. I want the divs to be left-aligned while centered.

Comment: Could you clarify further as I don't fully understand the question? What do you mean by _centering the `div`s_? Centering the _content_ of each `div`? Centering horizontally or/and vertically?

Comment: I wanna center left-aligned divs horizontally and vertically with no gaps in-between them. Just like centering a single container with multiple divs in it.

Comment: Just to clarify, by _left-aligned divs_ do you mean _divs with left-aligned content_? In your second example, the grid items have their content centered.

Comment: Yeah, I want to center divs with left-aligned content with no gaps in between them. In the second example, I'm trying to emphasize a grid container that takes up necessary space. In this way, I can just center the container. However, inline-grid doesn't want me to do just that.

Answer (score 0):

You can try another way by adding a **wrapper** class to cover all div. Then you use **justify-content:center** and **align-items:center** to center it.
In **wrapper** class, you use flex and flex-wrap to make it is left-aligned.

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  background-color: DodgerBlue;
  algin-items:center;
  justify-content: center;
}
.wrapper {
  width:420px;
  display:flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  background-color:red;
}
.wrapper > div {
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  width: calc(100% / 3);
  padding: 10px;
  font-size: 30px;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="wrapper">
  <div>1</div>
  <div>2</div>
  <div>3</div>  
  <div>4</div>
  <div>5</div>
  <div>6</div>  
  <div>7</div>
  <div>8</div>
  <div>9</div>  
  <div>10</div>
  <div>11</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: The solution is alright. Although, the divs are not responsive anymore. The divs squish instead of piling up.

Answer (score 0):

in my opinion div container should have attribute width based on screen size. in my code i use `width : 80%;` of screen size and add `margin : 0 auto;` for centering the div container.

```css
.container {
  font-size: 0;
  background-color: DodgerBlue;
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 80%;
}

.container>div {
  display: inline-block;
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
  width: 210px;
  line-height: 75px;
  font-size: 30px;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div>1</div>
  <div>2</div>
  <div>3</div>
  <div>4</div>
  <div>5</div>
  <div>6</div>
  <div>7</div>
  <div>8</div>
  <div>9</div>
  <div>10</div>
  <div>11</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

Based on the clarification you provided through comments, I'd suggest you use `flex` with `justify-content: center;` as the container.

Should you need the flex items to be flexible, you could adjust the `flex-basis` value (or the third item in the `flex:` shorthand).

See if the modified snippet below works for what you intend.

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  background-color: DodgerBlue;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: center;
}

.container > div {
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  flex: 0 0 210px;
  width: 210px;
  padding: 10px;
  font-size: 30px;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div>1</div>
  <div>2</div>
  <div>3</div>  
  <div>4</div>
  <div>5</div>
  <div>6</div>  
  <div>7</div>
  <div>8</div>
  <div>9</div>  
  <div>10</div>
  <div>11</div>
</div>
```

Comment: There's one significant problem in this solution that I forgot to clarify, the divs themselves must be left-aligned. In the solution above, the div content is left-aligned but the divs themselves are centered.

Comment: I'm confused again. In your comment you said you want to _center divs horizontally and vertically_. So, the content of each `div` is left-aligned, I get it. The `div`s will be centered but somehow left-aligned? Do you mean nested containers?

Comment: See the updated answer snippet above. In it, the containers are nested, in which the outer container keeps the inner container centered, but the inner container has its child divs left-aligned.

Comment: I updated my question and added a picture at the end of it in order to clarify my question further. Thanks for the help, I appreciate it..

Answer (score -1):

Maybe try display: grid with grid-area's and leave one area unfilled? And set a width with percentages on the grid-items.